# Should I say "who want" or "who wants"?

Tags: grammatical-number, pronouns, verb-agreement, questions

I'm French and I need your help for one little thing.

I'm about to write a status on Facebook for some users of my app (most of them talk English) and I am wondering if I should say :

> Who want to get some coupons for my app ?

OR

> Who wants to get some coupons for my app ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When *who* is used as a "question word" at the beginning of a sentence, it's always treated as singular. This may be by convention, but it's an easy rule. Even when addressing a crowd of clamouring children all yelling, "Me! Me!", all of whom might receive something, one still asks "Who wants..."

When *who* is used as relative pronoun then its number and the matching verb form depend on the noun it's referring to:

> The **person** who **takes** the sword shall be King.
>   The **people** who **steal** the apples shall be jailed.